# Correct workflow when starting on a new webpage with apache2 (in ubuntu..)

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server

Okay, it's clearly been a while since I've used linux (and apache). I'm just trying to create a new folder "newdir" under /var/www/html/ and editing index.html, which I'm only allowed to do with sudo, so all my files are "rooted". :-(

..and then, when I go to www.myserver.com/newdir/index.html, it's forbidden! (suprising...NOT)

So, my question is this. How do I correctly do this? Must I add every folder in the .conf file or something? I really couldn't find an good howto for this.

What I've done so far: only installed apache2 on ubuntu, nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chown or if you made directories chown -R, a less secure option is to make the apache user a login user and do your work from there

Comment: Haha, was THAT all? Thought I've tried that, but thanks anyway. So I don't need to create an entry for each directory in any apache config?

Comment: the apache config deals with location / , and is recursive.

Comment: Okay, so when /var/www/ is defined I should be good to go? Anything else I should worry about?